# Where does SafariOnline (Safari Queue) store downloaded books?

Tags: applications, storage, ebook-reader

I used the [Safari Books Online](http://www.safaribooksonline.com/) "[Safari Queue](http://www.safaribooksonline.com/apps)" not Safari to Go app to download a book to its "Offline Bookbag". In what format is the book stored? I ask because I'm hoping to use a reader other than Safari's own app to read the downloaded book.

Comment: If it is storing the books in internal/external SD card then you can see the format for yourself. Probably inside `/sdcard/Android/com.safariflow.queue` or simply in another folder under `/sdcard/`. If not, then the last place would be its data directory `/data/data/com.safariflow.queue`. You would need root access to peek into that directory.

Comment: do my phone need to be root ? @Firelord

Comment: If the book is stored in any SD card then you need not to have root access. If it is in data directory of the app then you would need root access to access that directory. Alternatively, you may attempt to backup that app using [tag:adb] to see whether it gives you anything or not.

Comment: no exactly not in sd card and would you mind explaining about adb? does it give the books ? @Firelord

Comment: If the books are stored in the data directory then you have a chance. Use ADB (see [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/96277)) to backup that particular app. You would succeed if the app allows itself to be backed up (I would bet on NO). Alternatively, having root access would take care of every problem here.

Comment: hmm there is no chance about its backup option, I have to make my phone root ? @Firelord

Comment: Well if the app doesn't want to be backed up and the books are not found in any SD card then you would have to root the device finally.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/qAJ5nbw.png now must I pass my phone to root mode ? @Firelord

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data is stored in `/data/data/com.safariflow.queue/app_data/`

---

Video books are stored in `/data/data/com.safariflow.queue/app_data/videos` folder.

[image: Video book]

---

Ebooks are stored in `data/data/com.safariflow.queue/app_data/books` folder - not as PDF, but as HTML folder (+supporting files css,jpg i.e metadata,images etc)

[image: Ebook folder 1]
[image: Ebook folder 2]

(*Maybe, they can be viewed (/rendered?) on web browsers*)

Comment: great but do you have root access or your phone is non-root ? Also, where the `data/data/com.safariflow.queue/app_data/` ? I can't find out the location

Comment: I've got root access,  You need root previliges. Its on /data partition

Comment: What is the format of books?

Comment: Ebooks are stored in `data/data/com.safariflow.queue/app_data/books` folder, not as pdf

Comment: @Firelord found that ebooks are stored as folders with html files

Comment: These HTML files are encrypted. Any idea how to decrypt them?